# Mememory Corruption in @property

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I have the next piece of code, one iVar with this property retained and released in it's class `dealloc` method. The iVar is used in 2 methods and continually change the value but 
sometimes when I use the value is corrupted. Why is that?

.h

```
@interface ChatController : NSObject <ASIHTTPRequestDelegate>{
NSTimer *timer;
NSString *_idLastMessageFromServer;
}

@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *idLastMessageFromServer;
@end
```

.m

```
@implementation ChatController

@synthesize idLastMessageFromServer = _idLastMessageFromServer;

- (void)initLoopTimer{
timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:5 target:self selector:@selector(update:) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
}

- (void)update:(id)sender{
ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:CONSTANT_YYYY];
[request setDelegate:self];
[request addPostValue:_idLastMessageFromServer forKey:CONSTANT_XXX];
[request setDidFinishSelector:@selector(requestUpdateFinish:)];
[request startAsynchronous];
}

- (void)requestUpdateFinish:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request{
NSString *response = [request responseString];
if(response && response.length){
    if(![response isEqualToString:CHAT_RESPONSE_NO_MESSAGES]){
        NSArray *array = [response componentsSeparatedByString:CHAT_PARSE_RESPONSE];
        if(array && [array count] == 2){
            **_idLastMessageFromServer = [array objectAtIndex:0];**
        }
     }
   }
}
```

But when the loop calls the method **update:**, it crashes in this line of code

```
[request addPostValue:_idLastMessageFromServer forKey:CONSTANT_XXX];
```

with EXC_BAD_ACCESS message, but why?

Comment: You should probably correct the spelling of the title to help people when they search for memory corruption.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By using `_idLastMessageFromServer` instead of `self.idLastMessageFromServer`, you are not retaining the string. The allows the retain count to drop to zero which deallocates the object. At that point you have a reference to bad memory, hence the app crashes.

Don't use iVars directly unless you have a good reason (like -init or -dealloc). Use the property instead.

```
 [request addPostValue:self.idLastMessageFromServer forKey:CONSTANT_XXX];
```

and

```
self.idLastMessageFromServer = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

---

I'll add a bit more of a detailed explanation about properties.

`self.idLastMessageFromServer` when used to read the value of the property calls an auto generated method `-idLastMessageFromServer`. This method will look something like:

```
- (NSString *)idLastMessageFromServer
{
    return _idLastMessageFromServer;
}
```

`self.idLastMessageFromServer` when used to set the value of the property calls an auto generated method `-setIdLastMessageFromServer:`. This method will look something like:

```
- (void)setIdLastMessageFromServer:(NSString *)idLastMessageFromServer
{
    if (_idLastMessageFromServer != idLastMessageFromServer) {
        [_idLastMessageFromServer release];
        _idLastMessageFromServer = idLastMessageFromServer;
        [_idLastMessageFromServer retain];
    }
}
```

One final note: be sure to release _idLastMessageFromServer in your `-dealloc` method. Something like:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    [_idLastMessageFromServer release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

---

More details about properties and iVars.

Properties (like self.idLastMessageFromServer) are simply a easy way to handle getter and setter methods. They cannot hold data because they are methods. iVars (like _idLastMessageFromServer) are a pointer to a location in memory. They cannot control access and maintain state because they are simply a pointer.

Properties and iVars work together.

The line `@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *idLastMessageFromServer;` says that somewhere in my implementation, my class will have a getter and setter for the property idLastMessageFromServer.

The line `@synthesize idLastMessageFromServer = _idLastMessageFromServer;` auto generates the getter and setter methods for idLastMessageFromServer using the iVar _idLastMessageFromServer.

In short, the property controls access to the iVar; the iVar is the storage location for the property.

Comment: Right now I'm going to try it but if your'e right why is this because when I do @synthesize idLastMessageFromServer = _idLastMessageFromServer;  _idLastMessageFromServer is the same like self.idLastMessageFromServer or not?

Comment: No it's not. _idLastMessageFromServer is a variable. self.idLastMessageFromServer is a method call to either -idLastMessageFromServer or -setIdLastMessageFromServer: (see [Declared Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html))

Comment: Thanks @Jeffery Thomas but if there is diferente for why use _idLastMessageFromServer why need to create an iVar if only the property is used (self.idLastMessage). why need to declare` NSString *_idLastMessageFromServer;` and `@synthesize idLastMessageFromServer = _idLastMessageFromServer;` because not only declare the `@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *idLastMessageFromServer;`  better and `@synthesize idLastMessageFromServer;` and not use iVar `_idLastMessageFromServer`.

Comment: I've updated my answer with more details about properties and iVars.

Comment: Hi @Jeffery Thomas these definitely solve my headache but Still have one Issues in the **dealloc method** what I have to send to release `[self.idLastMessageFromSever release];` or `[_idLastMessageFromSever release]` and why? please @Jeffery Thomas dont leave me alone. :)

Comment: In `-dealloc`, use `[_idLastMessageFromSever release]`. The quick answer is `-dealloc` should bypass the access control provided by the property. In addition, all init methods, the property getter, and the property setter should bypass access control and use the iVar directly.

Answer (score 5):

This line:

```
_idLastMessageFromServer = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

should probably be

```
self.idLastMessageFromServer = [array objectAtIndex:0];
```

This would access the property instead of the variable directly, thus triggering the retain / release during the assignment. Otherwise, the pointer is assigned, but the object taken from the array is not retained, it may quickly become invalid and you are left with a pointer pointing to a released object.

Comment: Right now I'm going to try it but if your'e right why is this because when I do @synthesize idLastMessageFromServer = _idLastMessageFromServer;  _idLastMessageFromServer is the same like self.idLastMessageFromServer or not?

Comment: No, not the same. The _idLastMessageFromServer is the actual pointer, while the self.idLastMessageFromServer is syntactic sugar for some code that does a retain. I think it's something like `if (nil != _x) { [_x release]; } _x = newValue; [_x retain];`

Comment: Thanks @craigmj but if there is diferente for why use _idLastMessageFromServer why need to create an iVar if only the property is used (self.idLastMessage).

Comment: Thanks @craigmj but if there is diferente for why use _idLastMessageFromServer why need to create an iVar if only the property is used (self.idLastMessage). why need to declare` NSString *_idLastMessageFromServer;` and `@synthesize idLastMessageFromServer = _idLastMessageFromServer;` because not only declare the `@property(nonatomic, retain)NSString *idLastMessageFromServer;`  better and `@synthesize idLastMessageFromServer;` and not use iVar `_idLastMessageFromServer`.

Comment: Basically, you have 2 choices: Either you use the iVar and you manually retain and release when assigning the variable, or you use the property that do all this for you. The property has the advantage or doing all this, but your have to be consistent, always use self. idLastMessageFromServer when accessing the property. Also, in your case, the property gives public access to idLastMessageFromServer. In your case, it would probably be better to use the iVar directly, or at least create a private category in the .m with a property to avoid exposing it publicly.